# Responsive background image height

Tags: css, wordpress, background

**Scenario :**

- I have a Wordpress site which has an old theme and doesn't allow me to change the header image.
- As a workaround on a page where I want a different image, I have
  hidden the header image using CSS and replaced it with a background
  image, which works fine and is responsive.

**Todo :**

- However I needed to set a height for the area in order to make a space for the **bg image to show up at full size (which I have done using a "padding-top")**

  - which causes a large space underneath the background image whenever
    the window is resized down, or on phones.
- Is there a way to make the
  space underneath the image collapse down as the image also collapses
  down?

**URL:** http://www.annareynolds.org/lovehobart/

**My Custom CSS:**

```
.singular-page-691 #header img {
    display:none;
}
.singular-page-691 #branding {
padding-top:390px;
  background-image:url(http://www.annareynolds.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/love-hobart-crop.jpg);  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
background-position:top left;
}
```

Comment: You  cannot change element by background size, either use javascript or img tag. But since you are using wordpress unless you go deep in code in file where that image is stored in theme files. You won't be able to change it

Comment: Can you provide the link to the deployed site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**only use padding in %**

like:

```
.singular-page-691 #branding {
padding-top: 40%;}
```

http://prntscr.com/kj6z3j

Comment: Thanks RamNiwas Sharma. This is a perfect solution and works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have visited the link you have provided and checked the responsive. I assume that I worked on the right place as your question asked.

You have `paddding-top:390px` in `.singular-page-691 #branding` It cause the space you mentioned. You can adjust the value of `padding-top` in responsive. I tried with `padding-top:180px` and it seems fine for me.